# Enable JMX in Tomcat docker container

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to enable JMX on tomcat docker image using `docker-compose.yml` but I'm still getting error that VisualVM cannot connect to the JMX.

```
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:8.0-jre8
    environment:
     CATALINA_OPTS: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
```

Comment: Are you able to see that 9000 port is open after tomcat server is started ?

Comment: Yes, it's open, I checked it using `nmap`

Answer (score 1):

JMX requires more than just a single port since RMI is also involved. Remote JMX is always a challenge with Tomcat, and using Docker basically makes this "remote" access.

Have a look at Tomcat's [JMX Remote Lifecycle Listener](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener) to see the port numbers that can be set, and *use that listener to set them*. If you don't, the RMI server is basically free to use whatever ports it wants to use and you can't predict them.

Once you set those ports, give the port mapping to Docker and you should be good to go.